# Refining Factors in Python

Tags: python

I have to write a function **factor**, which takes an integer parameter **n**, and returns the least number from 2 through n-1 that divides n. If no such number exists, it returns -1.

I was able to create the function to find the factors, but am unsure on how to refine it to return the correct result.

```
def factors(n):
   i = n
   lst=[]
   while i > 0:
      if n % i == 0:
         lst.append(i)
      i -= 1
   print(lst)
   result=[i for i in lst if i > 2 and i < n-1]
   print(result[1])



def main():
   n=int(input("Enter n:"))

   factors(n)

main()
```

Comment: you didn't return anything in your `factors(n)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, what does your program do at the moment, and where does it fail?

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension to find the factors of a number. Also, to optimize your solution, you only need to run until half of the number.

e.g. for 12, the maximum factor of 12 can be 6.

A number greater than half of that number can't be its factor. So, you do not require to run your loop until `n-1`.

```
>>> [n for n in range(2, number/2+1) if number % n == 0]
```

In the above line, we will run a loop from `2 to (number/2 + 1)` and check if the number is divisible by n, then add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your `factor` function should look from the smallest value first, then start increasing

```
def factor(n):
    i = 2
    while i < n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return i
        i += 1
    return -1

>>> factor(6)
2
>>> factor(21)
3
>>> factor(49)
7
>>> factor(13)
-1
```

Then `factors` can call that

```
def factors(n):
    values = [1]
    while n > 1:
        f = factor(n)
        if f > -1:
            values.append(f)
            n //= f
        else:
            values.append(n)
            break
    return values

>>> factors(21)
[1, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a lot of unnecessary work here: you find *all* factors, instead of just the smallest.  However, you *do* have a correct answer at your fingertips: you print the second element as the lowest factor, but your list is in the opposite order.  Try

```
print lst[-2]
```

That said you *really* should not bother with all of that.  Instead, start at 2 and work upward, looking for the smallest factor.  If you get to sqrt(n) without finding any, return a result of -1.

Comment: Upvote the pedagogical approach. You should add a hint though on a better way.

Comment: I did so, about the time you were typing your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is optimized way for finding factor of a number in between 2 or n-1:

```
def factor(n):
    i=2
    a=[]
    while i*i<=n:
        if n%i==0:
            if i!=n/i:
                a.append(i)
                a.append(n/i)
            else:
                a.append(i)
        i+=1
    a.sort()
    print a

n=int(input())
factor(n)
```